# How to get the pooled estimate and I-squared test for heterogeneity either in STATA or R

Tags: r, stata, meta-analysis

I am trying to do meta-analysis using a numerical variable (caculated dose value from different studies) with their sample sizes. I am planning to get the summary of the dose variable as follows with this equation: ni=sample size of that specific dose; dosei=dose value
Summary dose = Sum(ni*dosei)/Sum(ni)

This could calculate with excel. However, I have a question that is it possible to use meta-analysis commands such as 'meta summarize' or 'metan' to get this pooled estimate using only this dose (numerical variable) and sample size?
Also, to check the heterogeneity of this dose values across studies, is there any way to check this henetogeneity using I-squared test wither in stata or R?
I really appreciate your insightful comments for my request. Thank you!

Comment: The definition of heterogeneity embodied in $I^2$ relies on variance so the answer to that part of your questions is "No". Whether any of the myriad R packages for meta-analysis can answer your other question is, sadly, off-topic here as we do not do software recommendations. Off-hand I do not remember any being listed on https://cran.r-project.org/view=MetaAnalysis but I have not scanned it for a while.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarifications which is helpful to understand. Since the I2
  relies on variance, I was thinking that if I calculate the varaince based on the dose value and sample size: (dosei*dosei)/ni, and then use that varince to check the heterogeneity, would it make sense? I appreciate for your kind help to clarify this!

Comment: You need the between and within variance neither of which, as far as I can see, is going to be given by your formula.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am having a problem to solve this issue because I have only the 'calculated dose' values extracted from papers and their respective sample sizes.  Do you have any idea to get those variances from the data I have? or is it impossible to check the heterogeneity test with I2 in this situation? Thank you once again!